# Why project is not showing when import a android project from Github?

Tags: android, github

When I  "Checkout project from Version Control" a project from Github then project is not showing or loading but project downloaded in desire folder. Android studio is showing a error which is:[image]

[image]

Now what can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check version Control ???
i suggest see this link it can help you.
[Import Github project in AS](http://maxrohde.com/2014/08/18/import-github-project-to-android-studio/)

Comment: I did all those things but this error is occurring every time.